# Initializing Associative Array in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

Using PL/SQL, suppose we've declared a nested table type and its instance as follows:

> `type nested_tab is table of pls_integer;`
>   `tab nested_tab;`.

We are then able to initialize our nested table as follows:

> `tab := nested_tab(1, 2, 3);`.

Is there something similar we can do to initialize an associative array?

In other words, for the following associate array:

> `type associative_tab is table of varchar2(100) index by pls_integer;`
>   `a_tab associative_tab;`

is there a shorter way than this:

> `a_tab(1) := 'hello';`
>   `a_tab(2) := 'world';`
>   `...`
>   `a_tab(100) := '100th string';`

for intialization?

Comment: I don't think there's a shorter way to do it; if there is, it would probably be here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i20453

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer for 18c and beyond**

In 18c Oracle has introduced [qualified expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758) that can also be used to initialize an associative array. Example from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758):

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_aa IS TABLE OF BOOLEAN INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_aa1 t_aa := t_aa(1=>FALSE,
                     2=>TRUE,
                     3=>NULL);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(print_bool(v_aa1(1)));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(print_bool(v_aa1(2)));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(print_bool(v_aa1(3)));
END;
```

See also chapter *Qualified Expressions for Associative Arrays* from [Easy Initializing for Records and Arrays](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/easy-initializing-for-records-and-arrays) by [Steven Feuerstein](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/steven-feuerstein)

**Original answer upto 12c**

No - there is no a short-cut syntax to initialize an associative array. Unlike varrays and nested tables associative arrays do not have [collection constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00504).

Instead you should write your own initializer function. See an example from [Declaring Associative Array Constants](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99857).

Comment: they certainly do in 18c and above  myVar := myTable(); works 100%